# Named Query is not been loaded in the REST server connected to hyperledger composer and fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a query file called `queries.qry`

And I am trying to query my assets and transaction for now.

my code

```
//queries.qry
query AllAssetData {
  description: "Returns All the data in th registry"
  statement: 
    SELECT org.consentmanagement.asset.x
}

query AllTransactionData {
  description: "Returns All the data in th registry"
  statement: 
    SELECT org.consentmanagement.transactions.y
}
```

Now after creating a bna file and then a card. I Deployed it on the fabric I have using composer.(Using following code)

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile example.bna 

composer network start --networkName trial --networkVersion 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file admin@trial.card 

composer card import --file admin@trial.card 

composer network ping --card admin@trial
```

And deploy a REST server with it using

```
composer-rest-server -c admin@ltrial -n never -u true -d a -w true
```

Now when I open `localhost:3000`
and click on "Query: Named queries "

I don't get the queries I have coded, I just get this

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
The composer-rest-server was not updating as it was still following version `0.0.1`. (Which was the older version that did not have queries)
The solution is to change your versions to change `0.0.1` to`0.0.2` in your `package.json`
and upgrade the network by following steps

```
composer archive create -t dir -n . -a dist/trial.bna 
cd dist/
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile trial.bna

composer network upgrade -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -n *nameOfnetwork -V 0.0.2
```

and relaunch your `composer-rest-server`

Use This If you are stuck somewhere

```
composer archive create --help
composer network --help
composer network install --help
composer network upgrade --help
```